# How to pass Data from a UI Component Form to a Controller?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, blocks, controllers, adminform

Hey I'm beginner at Magento 2, and i don't know to much about UI component...

I'm creating a register form, and i want to **pass Data** of a **UI Component** **Form** to a **Controller**.

So i have a **Form** and i got a **Button** that i want to use it to get value from a **dropdown field(combobox)** of the **Form**.

I made the **Block** and the **Controller**, ok, the **Block** is calling the **Controller** right. But i don't know how to pass a specific value of the form to the controller. How can i do this?

I tried to use this command:  `$this->getRequest()->getParams();` but only returns ID and KEY.

And when i tried this command: `$this->getRequest()->getPostValue();` it just returns an empty array...

Any help is appreciated !

**DeleteHeader.php (Controller):**

```
 public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

    $this->save->getCombo();

    $txt = 'DELETE HEADER : ' .  $id;
    $this->logger->log('DEBUG', $txt);

    return $resultRedirect->setPath('api/data/edit/id/' . $id);
}
```

**DeleteHeader Block (Button):**

```
public function getButtonData()
{
    $url = $this->getUrl("api/data/deleteheader", ['id' => $this->getDataId()]);
    return [
        'label' => __('Delete Header'),
        'class' => 'custom-button-class',
        'data_attribute' => [
            'mage-init' => [
                'button' => ['event' => 'deleteheader'],
            ],
        ],
        'on_click' => "confirmSetLocation(' Certeza ? ','" . $url . " ')",
        'sort_order' => 80,
    ];
}
```

Comment: did you eventually succeed? thanks for letting us your feedback Rafael

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have exactly the same behavior, params have only id and form_key without any other data from fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$getParams = $this->getRequest()->getParam('myparam');
```

this is fine to use a get params. However your controller has to be a get controller `class MyAction extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements HttpGetActionInterface` if you want to use get parameters.

I wrote a repository for you to take a look:
https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/controllerwithjavascript/src/master/

Comment: Your repository is related to the frontend, It's strange(probably for me), but in frontend, I used something like request->getContent() instead of params or post value. It's not working for backend - getParams() or getPostValue() have id+form_key and empty respectively, getContent is empty as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use This in Your Controller File...

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
```

Then You Can Use Form value using `$post['your_field_name']`

Comment: I tried this, it returns an empty array.

Comment: plz share your code of controller file

Comment: I updated, using this code, the only params that i can get are ID and Key