# How to get Data of a UI Component Admin Form and use it in Controller?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent, forms, dropdown-attribute

So i'm creating a UI Component **Admin Form** with a few fields, and one of them is a **Dropdown field**.

I want to get the value that **user selects**, using a custom controller that i made.

I tried this comands:
`$this->getRequest()->getParams();` but only returns **ID** and **KEY**. What can i don to get all data of the form?

`$this->getRequest()->getPostValue();` i tried this one too, but don't works.

Well, but when i use those commandson the **Save Controller** it works, however thats not functional for me, because i want this to works when i call the **DeleteHeader Controller**. Why on the **Save Controller** works? thats because this tag `<submitUrl>` on the **Form.xml**: ?

```
<settings>
      <submitUrl path="api/data/save"/>
</settings>
```

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: i think it was solved here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315752/how-to-pass-data-from-a-ui-component-form-to-a-controller